# how to create a qtablewidget with custom header

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to create an exact copy of the following table in `Qt`

[image]

How would I create a header like that? Is there a way to do it in `Qt`?

Comment: Try [QTableWidget::setSpan(int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan);](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSpan) for merging. :-?

Answer (score 1):

You could customize every single header column by using [setHorizontalHeaderItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setHorizontalHeaderItem) or just set the text in all column header by using [setHorizontalHeadersLabels](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setHorizontalHeaderLabels).

An easy way to implement your attached image is by customizing your own QWidget. Use a vertical layour and consider your Icp (mA) header as a custom label with a center alignment.

Then insert your QTableWidget and set the headers as (3kOmega, 5.1kOmega & 11kOmega). Something like this:

```
QWidget* container = new QWidget(this);
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

// Custom label
QLabel* header = new QLabel(this);
header->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
header->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
header->setText("Icp (mA)");

// Custom QTableWidget
QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget(this);
table->setColumnCount(3);
QStringList LIST;
LIST << "3k" << "11k" << "15k";
table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(LIST);
table->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

layout->addWidget(header);
layout->addWidget(table);
container->setLayout(layout);
setCentralWidget(container);
```

Giving you something like this:

[image]